# Where is Rails.root directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Ruby on Rails project, we are going to save the log in the log folder.

```
Rails.logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'server.log'))
```

But I could not find this log in var/log...

Can you tell me where is the Rails.root??

Answer (score 1):

`Rails.root` is just where you are storing your code files on the file system, nothing really magical about it.
You can go see it with `rails c` and doing

```rb
Rails.root.to_s
```